# Is it ok to indirectly attribute an idea to an author without explicitly naming the author and giving explicit attribution?

Tags: creative-writing

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sFvf6Elp3D0

So I would like to write a science-fiction novel where the idea of "The Dark Forest" is used. The idea of "The Dark Forest" comes from Liu Cixin. So is it ok for me to use that idea and name it "The Dark Forest" in the novel without explicitly naming Liu Cixin in any way or form? I am thinking by the fact you're using the term "The Dark Forest" people would already think of Liu Cixin so giving explicit attribution is not needed at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Imitation is the most sincere form of flattery

Ideas are not owned, they are not third party content, and do not need attribution. In fact they are very rarely original. For example, both J. R. R. Tolkien's and [C. S. Lewis](https://apilgriminnarnia.com/2013/03/04/be-careful-what-you-read-c-s-lewis-literary-encounter-with-george-macdonald/)' worlds [are knock-offs of George MacDonald](https://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/George_MacDonald). *Avatar*, the whole story, [is *Dances With Wolves*](https://www.mtv.com/news/mdui65/avatar-and-dances-with-wolves-how-similar-are-they), the Na'vi translator Neytiri is Lakota translator [Stands With a Fist](https://hero.fandom.com/wiki/Stands_With_A_Fist), [amputee soldier Jake Sully](https://pelicandiaries.files.wordpress.com/2010/09/avatar-jake-wheelchair.jpg) who recovers his leg through the 'avatar' is [Lieutennant John Dunbar](https://i0.wp.com/www.thatmomentin.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Screen-Shot-2019-02-05-at-10.07.02-AM.png?w=922&ssl=1) who barely escaped leg amputation. The Star Wars franchise has almost no original content at all, it is simply a retelling of Alex Raymond's *Flash Gordon*. Darth Vader is Ming the Merciless. 'Cloud City' is '[Sky City](https://flashgordon.fandom.com/wiki/Sky_City)'. The city's ruler, Lando Calrissian is [Prince Vultan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prince_Vultan), who even [won the city in a gambling bet](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Cloud_City) just like Vultan, and has a crush on the leading Lady (Princess Leia / Dale Arden), and is subservient to the evil empire (Vader/Ming). The undersea city of Otoh Gunga is [the Undersea City](https://flashgordon.fandom.com/wiki/Kala%27s_city) and its ruler [King Rugor Nass](https://starwars.fandom.com/es/wiki/Rugor_Nass?file=Jedi_Mind_Trick_SoH.webp) is [King Kala](https://flashgordon.fandom.com/wiki/King_Kala?file=103kalaskinnyandbuff.jpg). Every Star Wars idea was created by Alex Raymond. But who "owns" the worlds of Cloud City, Otoh Gungam, Luke Skywalker, Darth Vader, the Death Star, and every other knock-off? They are firmly George Lucas' worlds. Every episode of Star Trek is a knock-off of something popular at the time. The [Kradin](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/f/p/3343172654596368116) are the Yautia ([Predator](https://www.slashfilm.com/660450/everything-we-know-about-prey-the-predator-prequel-so-far/)). Star Trek: Discovery's new Klingon clans are all [inspired by ancient Earth civilizations](https://www.cnet.com/culture/entertainment/star-trek-discovery-klingons-inspired-by-the-ancients/), and the first Klingons were Soviets. Now, The Orville is a knock-off of Star Trek. Put a "Dark Forest" in your world and it is still your world, not Liu Cixin's. Put a light-sabre-like sword in your world and it is still YOUR world. Put a Predator-like creature in your world and it is still YOUR world. Put a Mi-Go like creature into your world and it is still YOUR world, your property.

George Lucas *loved* Flash Gordon so much that he tried to buy the rights to it, and that was what he wanted to produce. But they would not sell it to him. So he copied the whole story and called it Star Wars. This is a *tribute* to Flash Gordon, not a theft of it. If you are inspired by someone else's great story, go ahead and make a tribute piece. Retell it in your own words. They should be honored to be an inspiration.

### Caveat:

While you may not be in any actual legal trouble for reusing *The Dark Forest,* nothing can stop them from trying to sue you. Even Star Wars spent millions of dollars in legal fights with Battlestar Galactica, because Lucas claimed Galactics was a [derivative work](https://www.law.cornell.edu/wex/derivative_work#:%7E:text=Derivative%20work%20refers%20to%20a,off%20of%20the%20original%20product.) of his Star Wars. Lucas lost the law suit because there was "substantial change the content of the work," and Galactica did not "incorporate enough of the original work that it obviously stems from the original." But the cost of these legal fights alone can completely kill your product, so it may be wise to come up with a clever name that is close to Dark Forest but not use those words exactly. I think "The Black Wood" is pretty cool, or change it to "jungle." Again, you're doing nothing objectively wrong. A different name only provides a layer of protection from attempted legal challenges.

This is how [The Asylum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_The_Asylum_films) is able to make money off blockbuster movies all the time. It is the only thing they do. Look at *Godzilla vs. Kong* and [Ape vs. Monster](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt14516188/), which came out so fast it released in the same year as GvK.

### Note, changing language may be enough

If you are bilingual you will likely be safe by simply translating another work entirely. The English print of *The Dark Forest* translated by Joel Martinsen has some differences from the Chinese original, such as Frederick Tyler's designs. Thus, an exact English translation of Cixin's story does not yet exist, and it is likely that Cixin would not be legally protected against someone doing so. I would not attempt this unless I were willing to fight it in court, however.

Comment: However, if something is judged to be a derivative work, then it will still be considered breach of copyright. Take for example [Tanya Grotter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tanya_Grotter). So be sure to use other works *only* as inspiration, take ideas and give them your own twist, avoid copying the implementation of an idea.

Answer (score 2):

The Dark Forest is too generic to be a reference to any work.

A more pointed reference can be an *allusion* to another work, and no, does not need attribution.